# Windows 11 Audio Not Working For Single User Profile

Tags: audio, windows-11

I just bought a new HP laptop with Windows 11. I'm at home, so not on a domain, and all I've done is add two users. The sound doesn't work for a single user profile. Sound doesn't play when using the Windows audio test. I tried resetting the sound settings.